# Create Bootstrap grid with JS loop

Tags: javascript, css, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to iterate a JSON array and print the results inside a row (3 equal columns). The actual method don't respect the logic behind bootstrap, so how can I tell JS to include only 3 elements then clone a similar div. Here's a runnable code so you can have a feel of the issue. Should be viewed on large screens. Thanks.

```js
var url = "https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries?order_by=count&sort=desc";

  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
      $('#data').append(
          $('<h2>').text(result.name),
          $('<div>').text("Code = " + result.code),
          $('<div>').text("Score = " + result.count),
          $('<hr>').text("  "),
        );
    });

  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

    <h1></i>Open, real-time and historical air quality data</h1> 

    <hr>


    <div class="row" style="background-color: #ddd">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="data" style="background-color: #fe8000" ></div>
    </div>

    <h6 style="padding-bottom: 25px">Source: This data is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 Generic License. It is attributed to OpenAQ. 
    The software is licensed as below with The MIT License.</h6>

</div> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: you want a table grid with 3 columns printing the data from json and clone this single row to appending and display remaining json data.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGhule You mean clone in JS? because in HTML is not working.

Comment: not cloning exactly but just similar to copy html markup (tr) for first row and display remaining data in next consecutive rows @Blacksun

Comment: It's not working because your putting them all inside a single "col-md-4", you of course need 3..

Comment: @Keith I tried creating 3 different md-4 in a single row. Also, in multiple rows.

Comment: @Blacksun do you want tabular format grid with 3 columns in each row to display your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code slightly modified to do your 3 columns.

Please note, you had some extra colouring in there.  I removed because it didn't look very nice.  That's because ideally full height div's would look better.   In some respects not using twitters grid system and using flexbox might give better results.

Please note you will need to go into fullscreen with this snippet, or you wont see the 3 columns for obvious reason.  That or change the col-md-4  to col-xs-4..

```js
var url = "https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries?order_by=count&sort=desc";

  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
      $('#data').append(
          $('<h2 class="col-md-4">').text(result.name),
          $('<div class="col-md-4">').text("Code = " + result.code),
          $('<div class="col-md-4">').text("Score = " + result.count),
        );
    });

  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

    <h1></i>Open, real-time and historical air quality data</h1> 

    <hr>

    <div class="row" style="background-color: #ddd" id="data" style="background-color: #fe8000">
    </div>

    <h6 style="padding-bottom: 25px">Source: This data is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 Generic License. It is attributed to OpenAQ. 
    The software is licensed as below with The MIT License.</h6>

</div> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I'm tweaking your code to print h2, p, etc.. in one col-md-4 not create a table like you've done.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to add html tag in js function? something like:  $('<div class="col-md-4">').text(result.name + '<br>' + 
             '<h2>' +  "Code = " + result.code + '<br>' +  "Score = " + result.count)

Comment: You can use the html setter, instead of the text one.. eg..   `$('<div class="col-md-4">').html(result.name + '<br>' + '<h2>' + "Code = " + result.code + '<br>' + "Score = " + result.count)`

Answer (score 0):

View output of following code on screen width >= 992px;

I have not used table to create a grid consisting of 3 columns in each row instead used div (as in your case).

Just created dynamic div with `class col-md-4` and displayed each data from json response and appended it to current `div#data`.

```js
let url = "https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries?order_by=count&sort=desc";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
 let divContent = '<h2>'+result.name+'</h2>'+
      '<div>'+result.code+'</div>'+
      '<div>'+result.count+'</div>';
 let div = "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4' data-idx="+i+">"+divContent+"</div>";
    
 $('#data').append(div);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Open, real-time and historical air quality data</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row" style="background-color: #ddd">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="data" style="background-color: #fe8000">         </div>
  </div>
  <h6 style="padding-bottom: 25px">
  Source: This data is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 Generic License. It is attributed to OpenAQ.The software is licensed as below with The MIT License.
 </h6>
</div>
```

Hope, this works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This version print separate `mid-col-4` with some infos from the API request:

```js
  var url = "https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries?order_by=count&sort=desc";

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

  $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
    $('#data').append(
      $('<div class="col-md-4" style="padding: 30px; border-top: 1px solid #F6F6F6">').html
      ('<h2>' + result.name + '</h2>' + "Code = " +  result.code + '<br>' + "Score = " + result.count),
  );

  });


});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Open, real-time and historical air quality data</h1>
  <hr>
  
<div class="row" id="data"></div

  <h6 style="padding-bottom: 25px">
  Source: This data is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 Generic License. It is attributed to OpenAQ.The software is licensed as below with The MIT License.
 </h6>
</div>
```